# Combine three text files

Tags: vb.net

How does one combine three text files together into one? I was also trying to make it alphabetical by state in the new text file. I figured how to combine two but three I am getting lost.

```
Public Class newsenatefrm
    Dim current() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("Senate113.txt")
    Dim retired() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("RetiredSen.txt")
    Dim newSen() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("NewSen.txt")

    Dim queryCurrent = From line In current
                       Let state = Split(","c)(1)
                       Let name = Split(","c)(0)
                       Let party = Split(","c)(2)
                       Order By state Ascending
                       Select state, name, party

    Dim queryRetired = From line In retired
                       Let state = Split(","c)(1)
                       Let name = Split(","c)(0)
                       Let party = Split(","c)(2)
                       Order By state Ascending
                       Select state, name, party

    Dim queryNew = From line In newSen
                   Let state = Split(","c)(1)
                   Let name = Split(","c)(0)
                   Let party = Split(","c)(2)
                   Order By state Ascending
                   Select state, name, party
    Private Sub generatebtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles generatebtn.Click

        IO.File.WriteAllText("Senate114.txt")
    End Sub
End Class
```

I included sample text from the three text files below:

> Senate113.txt:
> Richard Shelby,Alabama,R
> Bernard Sanders,Vermont,I
> Kristen Gillibrand,New York,D

> Retired.txt:
> John Rockefeller,West Virginia,D
> Tom Coburn,Oklahoma,R
> Carl Levin,Michigan,D

> NewSen.txt:
> Shelly Capito,West Virginia,R
> Steve Daines,Montana,R
> Gary Peters,Michigan,D

Answer (score 1):

As you're just learning Visual Basic, you might enjoy finding some new things in this answer.

You've got files with the data separated by commas, a common format known as a [comma-separated values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file, or CSV file. There are several parsers available for that format, I'm just using the [TextFieldParser Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser) because it comes with VB.NET.

If you're going to be working with data, it is very often a good idea to make a *class* for the data items - it allows you to keep associated data together, with sensible names, and provide methods that work with that data.

So, you could have one main List(Of Senator) to which you can add more data (senators) from a file, perhaps like this:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO

Module Module1

    Public Class Senator
        Property Name As String
        Property State As String
        Property Party As String

        Public Sub New()
            ' Empty constructor
        End Sub

        Public Sub New(name As String, state As String, party As String)
            Me.Name = name
            Me.State = state
            Me.Party = party
        End Sub

        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return $"{Name}, {State}, {Party}"
        End Function

    End Class

    Function GetSenators(fromFile As String) As List(Of Senator)
        Dim s As New List(Of Senator)

        Using csvReader As New TextFieldParser(fromFile)
            csvReader.Delimiters = {","}

            While Not csvReader.EndOfData
                Dim parts = csvReader.ReadFields()
                If parts.Count = 3 Then
                    s.Add(New Senator(parts(0), parts(1), parts(2)))
                End If
            End While

        End Using

        Return s

    End Function

    Sub Main()
        Dim srcDir = "C:\temp"
        Dim srcFiles = {"Senate113.txt", "RetiredSen.txt", "NewSen.txt"}

        Dim combinedSenators As New List(Of Senator)

        For Each f In srcFiles
            Dim actualFile = Path.Combine(srcDir, f)
            combinedSenators.AddRange(GetSenators(actualFile))
        Next

        Dim senatorsByState = combinedSenators.OrderBy(Function(sen) sen.State).Select(Function(s) s.ToString())
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(vbCrLf, senatorsByState))

        'File.WriteAllLines("C:\temp\Senate114.txt", senatorsByState)

        Console.Write("Finished.")
        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Which, with the sample data in the question, outputs:

```
Richard Shelby, Alabama, R
Carl Levin, Michigan, D
Gary Peters, Michigan, D
Steve Daines, Montana, R
Kristen Gillibrand, New York, D
Tom Coburn, Oklahoma, R
Bernard Sanders, Vermont, I
John Rockefeller, West Virginia, D
Shelly Capito, West Virginia, R
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible ways, but as it looks like the files you're dealing with will be quite small, you could read them all into a List(Of String) to start with:

```
Dim a = IO.File.ReadLines("C:\temp\Senate113.txt").ToList()
a.AddRange(IO.File.ReadLines("C:\temp\RetiredSen.txt"))
a.AddRange(IO.File.ReadLines("C:\temp\NewSen.txt"))
```

Then carry on as you did before, you just need to do it once instead of thrice.

(It's best to give a full path to a file.)

Comment: Hmmm. This way the lines in the output file are not sorted by state per input file. I think the OP asks to output the data from the LINQ queries into a single file.

Comment: @BartHofland The OP already has that code working.

Comment: Yes, I see that. But I fail to see how to OP's logic can be preserved with this rough code sample of yours. I understand what you are doing, and I would probably do something like that as well. Your answer hints in a direction, but it does not offer a solution, since your code currently does not seem to "fit" into the OP's code. You should also explain what to do with your collection `a` to attain the desired sorting. Or show a way to populate your collection `a` from the LINQ queries instead of directly from the input files.

Comment: @BartHofland `Dim query = From line In a` etc.

Comment: Yes, that might be correct. That was somewhat unclear to me. I assumed that the OP wanted to keep the current sorting logic in the single output file: first the lines from the first input file sorted by state, then the lines from the second input file sorted by state, and finally the lines from the third input file sorted by state.

Comment: Right. I was combining the three text files into one file and then in the combined final file, it would be then sorted by the senator's states.

Comment: Got the files combined into its output file. How does the query fit in IO.File.WriteAllLines("Senate114.txt", sen)

Comment: @TheOne Could you show us the definition of `sen` in your previous comment?